# Grab values from checked checkboxes and put them in an array using Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to get the values of checked checkboxes with the `name="car_type[]"` and alert the final array with all the values.
How to do that? So far, I have this code. But it's not working. I don't know how to loop through checked checkboxes properly and add the values to the array `car_type_arr`. I also cannot alert the final array using `alert(car_type_arr);`. Thanks for any help.

```
$().ready(function(){

        $('.prettycheckbox').click(function(e) {    

            e.preventDefault();

            var car_type_arr = [];

                $("input:checkbox[name=car_type]:checked").each(function()
                        {
                             // here I need to add values to array like in php
                             // e.g. $car_type_arr[] = $the_grabbed_value;
                             // but using javascript syntax
                             // How to do that?
                        });  

            // then I need to alert the array, how to do that in JS?
            alert(car_type_arr);

            return false;
        });

});
```

Comment: You can use car_type_arr.push(<value>);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below code:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="xxx">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="xxx1">
<input type="checkbox" name="chkBox" value="xxx2">
<input type="button" id="btnBox">

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#btnBox").click(function(){
        var car_type_arr = [];

        $("input:checkbox[name=chkBox]:checked").each(function() {                
            car_type_arr.push($(this).val());
            alert(car_type_arr);
    }); 
});
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/XDpBP/

Answer (score 2):

You can use `map`

```
var car_type_arr = $("input:checkbox[name=car_type]:checked").map(function() {
                        return this.value;
                   }).get();

console.log(car_type_arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("input:checkbox[name=car_type]:checked").each(function() {
    car_type_arr.push($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: `$("input:checkbox[name=car_type]").is(":checked")` will return boolean value, then how would you call `.each()` on boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("input:checkbox[name=car_type]:checked").each(function()
    {
        car_type_arr.push($(this).val());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

your code should look like,

```
$().ready(function(){

        $('.prettycheckbox').click(function(e) {    

            e.preventDefault();

            var car_type_arr = [];

                $("input:checkbox[name=car_type]").each(function()
                        {

                              if($(this).is(':checked')){
                                car_type_arr.push($(this).val());
                              }
                        });  

            alert(car_type_arr);

            return false;
        });

});
```